# Can't Google Analytics Event Tracking function before submit a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2, google-analytics

I'm trying to track a submit button with Google Analytics. But the problem is the submit is too fast, so GA don't track the event.

How is correct way to get this work? I'm using JSF 2.

```
$("#frmButtons\\:btnExportWord").click(function () {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Decode', 'Decode copying', 'Export to Word']);
});
```

I tried *hitcallback* function of GA but no success. I think this feature is not too well documented.

**Edit:**

I realized that *hitcallback* function is not what I need, once the button sends a file to user download, so, don't happen a navigation.

Comment: I tried hitcallback function of GA but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging the previous answers of @dSquared and @crmpicco I put this work using this:

```
$("#frmButtons\\:btnExportWord").click(function (e) {
  //track the event
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Decode', 'Decode copying', 'Export to Word']);

  var button = $(this);
  //create a delay and call the same click
  if (button.data('tracked') != 'true') {
      e.preventDefault(); //consume event if not tracked yet
      setTimeout( function(){
          button.data('tracked', 'true'); 
          button.click(); //call again the submit
      }, 300);//enough time to track the event
  } else {
      //reset the flag
      button.data('tracked', 'false');
      //let form being submited once the event is already tracked
  }
});
```

I really didn't like the solution, once I need to consume the event and after that, recall it recursively, but I'm not JS specialist, and I haven't found another solution that worked in any browser. JSF generated some code, calling the event again is the easy way to get it on server side.

Thanks guys from help!

Comment: I also documented what I learned from this: http://softwareisart.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/tracking-events-in-google-analytics-before-form-submit-jsf-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into a submit listener for the form, prevent the default submit event, trigger the Google Analytics Code and then submit the form manually like so:

```
$('#formID').submit(function(e){
    var self = this;

    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submit Event

    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Decode', 'Decode copying', 'Export to Word']);

    self.submit(); // Manually Trigger Submit
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/STdwr/).

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

If your form has multiple buttons and you only want to track on specific ones, consider applying a class onto the button you wish to track, and then checking for it when doing the submit like so:

HTML:

```
<form id="theForm" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Track Submit" class="track" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
// Identify Clicked Submit Button
$('#theForm input[type=submit]').on('click', function(){
    // Reset Previous Data
    $('#theForm input[type=submit]').data('clicked', 'false');

    // Set Button as Clicked
    $(this).data('clicked', 'true');
});

// Hook into Form Submit
$('#theForm').submit(function(e){
    var self = this;

    // Prevent Default Submit
    e.preventDefault();

    // Track ONLY if Clicked Button has Class of 'track'
    $('input[type=submit]', this).each(function(){
        if ($(this).data('clicked') == 'true' && $(this).hasClass('track') === true){
            alert('TRACK DATA');
        }
    });

    // Manually Submit Form
    self.submit();
});
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/STdwr/1/).

Comment: Google suggests for these cases to set a timeout on the submit event so their pixel has time to fire before the submit. I think simply doing the submit in javascript will by itself not be enough to ensure proper tracking.

Comment: The form has many buttons. The way you showed @dSquared, I will track all buttons, I need just one button, once the others are already being tracked.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but it does not worked. I think the problem is the file download, once it start, everything being submit is interrupted. The answer of @crmpicco worked in Safari and Firefox, even when the download start automatically, but not in Chrome. I'm considering doing this at server side, but I don't know if it is a good approach, I think more people have the same problem as mine.

Answer (score 1):

It is common that the page can change before the `_gaq` array has been populated and the beacon sent to Google. To get around this you can also consider using a JavaScript timeout as in the example below:

```
setTimeout(function() {                                                                         
// track now after 1000 ms
_gaq.push();                                                                                                                        
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It will be pushed after the submit of the page? Is javascript able to create another thread and do the push?

Comment: @compicco, It worked on Firefox, Safari, but not in Chrome. I think javascript is different there. All browsers the download started automatically as I want. What a pity! =/